# grunt failing due to parse error from commented out code

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, uglifyjs, grunt-contrib-concat, grunt-contrib-uglify

When I concat a bunch of js, including jquery, I get an error when I grunt complaining about 'unexpected token (]) at line 1019844...' and I look at that line, it has code that is commented out that should not be commented out

```
//# sourceMappingURL=jquery.min.map;define([
    "./core",
    "./var/rnotwhite",
    "./ajax/var/nonce",
    "./ajax/var/rquery",
    "./core/init",
    "./ajax/parseJSON",
    "./ajax/parseXML",
    "./deferred"
], function( jQuery, rnotwhite, nonce, rquery ) {
```

At the first row is a comment that should not be a comment, how would I deal with this for grunt without manual intervention?

edit: snippet of my gruntjs

```
concat: {
      // Specify some options, usually specific to each plugin.
       options:{
        separator: ';'
      },
      js: {
        src: ['<%= srcJavascript %>/**/*.js'],
        dest: '<%= concatJavascript %>/gtg-js.js'
      },
      css:{
        src: ['<%= srcCss %>/**/*.css'],
        dest: '<%= concatCss %>/gtg-css.css'   
      }    
    },  
    uglify: {
        build: {
            files :{
                '<%= targetJavascript %>/gtg-js-uglify.js':['<%= concatJavascript %>/gtg-js.js']
            }               
        },
        options: {
            banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("dd-mm-yyyy") %> */\n',
            compress: true,
            mangle: true
        }
    },
    cssmin: {
        css: {
            src:'<%= concatCss %>/gtg-css.css', 
            dest: '<%= targetCss %>/gtg-css-min'
        }
     }

.....
  // We've set up each task's configuration.
  // Now actually load the tasks.
  // This will do a lookup similar to node's require() function.
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');


  // Register our own custom task alias.
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat', 'uglify', 'cssmin']);
```

Comment: It seems you are you setting up sourceMap flag in option object, right? Do you really need that option? Try to provide setting for concat task.

Comment: I am not using sourceMap flag, don't know what that is but I will provide my settings in edit above

Comment: I would say that the issue may be caused by grunt concat task, when it reach end of the jQuery file there is a comment sourceMappingURL reference and following file is merge within the comment line which causing an error, but this is just theory. Try to following steps:
- replace latest jQuery min version, which doesn't contains that sourceMappingURL comment
- replace jQuery with uncompressed version
- you could also to merge a jQuery file in the end of the concat task

hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

After concatenating, replace this line:

```
//# sourceMappingURL=jquery.min.map;define([
```

with:

```
//# sourceMappingURL=jquery.min.map;
define([
```

There are two occurrences.